# How to set EditText box height and width programmatically in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to manage the height and width of an `EditText` box programmatically in Android. I tried `edittext.setWidth(32);` and `edittext.setEms(50);`, but both are not working. See my below code, as I am using it to create dynamic `EditText`s in Android.

```
private EditText createEditText()
{
    final LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    final EditText edittext = new EditText(this);
    edittext.setLayoutParams(lparams);
    edittext.setWidth(32);
    edittext.setEms(50);
    return edittext;
}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
private EditText createEditText()
{
    final LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(50,30); // Width , height
    final EditText edittext = new EditText(this);
    edittext.setLayoutParams(lparams);
    return edittext;
}
```

Try this.

Comment: Which `LayoutParams` to import ?

Comment: Need to import ViewGroup.LayoutParams

Comment: My editText is in a relativeLayout and this is the error I am getting                                                                                                                                                                                                              java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams

Comment: lparams height and width values in dp(density pixel)?

Answer (score 16):

```
edittext.getLayoutParams().width=32;
```

Comment: This causes me NullPointerExceptions... :-(

Answer (score 8):

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
final float height = metrics.heightPixels;

EditText edittext = new EditText(this);

edittext.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,(int) (height/2)));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.width = 32; 
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.height = 50;
```

works for me. for example

```
    lparams.width = 32;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) edittext.getLayoutParams();
            params.width = mScreenWidth / 5;
            params.height = mScreenWidth / 5;
            edittext.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score -2):

Try the following code:-

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
    int screenWidth = display.getWidth();
    int screenHeight = display.getHeight();

profile_pic.getLayoutParams().height=(screenHeight/6);
    profile_pic.getLayoutParams().width=(screenHeight/6);
```