# Unable to set EditText height using Java in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

This is my code :

```
LinearLayout llgrower= new LinearLayout(this);
int percent_x=80,percent_y=10;
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
edittextwidth = (int) ((int)(display.getWidth())*percent_x/100);
edittextheight= (int) ((int)(display.getHeight())*percent_y/100);
```

EditTextObject contains the default methods such as settext, setwidth, setheight etc

```
EditTextObject objedt=new EditTextObject(this);                         
objedt.setText("Some text");
objedt.setWidth(edittextwidth);
objedt.setHeight(edittextheight);
llgrower.addView(objedt);
```

setWidth is working properly, but setHeight is not working properly for Edittext. I tried the same code on TextView both setWidth and setHeight are working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this for set the hight of `edittext` smaller then the actual size. Also dont forget to `setTextSize` because there is some possibility for some part of your text will gone to invissible state.

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et);
et.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200,15)); 
et.setTextSize(10);
```

I hope this will help you. Thanks.

Comment: You cant have smaller edittext mr.anirud. why because if you go too smaller you cant see what ur typing.

Answer (score 0):

Try with **.setLayoutParams(***params***)**

Duplication of this topic?:

[how to set EditText box height and width programmatically in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9224927/how-to-set-edittext-box-height-and-width-programmatically-in-android)

```
...
final LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(10,20); // Width , height
final EditText edittext = new EditText(this);
edittext.setLayoutParams(lparams);
...
```