# LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT does not work but integer does

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, layoutparams

I am generating editTexts in a TableRow and the editTexts width is wrapping the content by default. I tried to set their width to match_parent like this:

```
TableRow tr = new TableRow(getActivity());
EditText et = new EditText(getActivity());

LayoutParams lparams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

et.setLayoutParams(lparams);
```

It did not change anything, but i can set their width if i replace `LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT` with an integer. Could you please point me in the right direction to see why i cannot set their width to `MATCH_PARENT`?

Comment: go through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50251052/how-to-change-the-width-of-an-edittext-object-programmatically/50251226?noredirect=1#comment87520668_50251226

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accidentally found out, that if i am not using a `TableRow`, but placing the `editTexts` into the `TableLayout` its width will automaticall match the parent's width.