# How to zoom on a EditText when focus?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, kotlin, layout

I have a ScrollView which contain a CustomView. In that CustomView I can have many EditText like this :

[image: First]

When I focus an EditText, I want to zoom on this EditText so that this EditText is in center of the screen and take the same width like the screen.

The expected result :

[image]

Sorry for my bad english, Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

EditText has **setOnFocusChangeListener** use it to see when EditText receives and looses focus.

```
     editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
     @Override
     public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
          if (hasFocus) {
              //Dynamically resize EditText to match device width
          } else {
              //Dynamically resize EditText to match previous width with margin
          }
      }
  });
```

You can change EditText width and height dynamically using LayoutParams as in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9224927/how-to-set-edittext-box-height-and-width-programmatically-in-android)

Comment: I want to resize the CustomView too, but how to make CustomView's borders "out" of screen ?